# IndexError While training a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, training-data

While training a sign language translation pre-developed code from GitHub for demonstration. While training a model, received a error.
Here,

> num_of_classes = 7
> Input_size=(50,50)
> The train image shape: (3670, 50, 50, 1) and
> Validation image shape : (367, 50, 50, 1)

> The train labels shape: (3670, 1008) and Validation labels shape : (367, 1008)

> ValueError: shape(None, 1008) and (None,7) are incompatible

I found that training label and validation label shape is mismatching because of input labels shape:

```
train_images = np.reshape(train_images, (train_images.shape[0],
image_x, image_y, 1))
val_images = np.reshape(val_images,(val_images.shape[0], image_x, image_y, 1)) 
train_labels = utils.to_categorical(train_labels)#,num_classes = 7) 
val_labels = utils.to_categorical(val_labels)#,num_classes = 7)
```

So, changed to

```
utils.to_categorical(val_labels,num_classes =7)
```

But, getting another,

> IndexError: index 1003 is out of bounds for
> axis 1 with size 7.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You have seven classes, but your categorical labels have a width of `1008`. Shouldn't the `val_labels` and `train_labels` have a shape of `(367, 7)` and `(3670, 7)` respectively? From the error message, it seems clear that your intent is for there to be 7 classes, but you're providing a vector size `1008`.

Comment: I have 7 classes. The class names are 1001,1002,1003, to 1007. Each class has 500 to 600 images in it. These classes are embedded with names in .db file. So, what should i do to change the vector size to 7

Comment: Perhaps you just need to make sure `val_labels` and `train_labels` is of type `tf.string`, even though the values are numeric. Ex: `val_labels = ["1001", "1002", ...]`. Without seeing your code and data, it's hard to debug.

Comment: That is bad advice, labels cannot be strings. Your labels before one-hot encoding need to be integers from 0 to num_classes - 1.

Comment: Obviously the labels going into the model need to be converted to an int. In his case, they're categorical, not numeric. You wouldn't want to have a one hot vector length 1,001. Instead, the four categories `("1001", "1002", "1003", "1004")` would be converted to class IDs `(0, 1, 2, 3)`. I was talking about the first step in this pipeline in my previous comment.

Comment: @rodrig0-silveira and Dr.Snoopy. The heartful thanks to both of you for helping me out. I given a lengthy index from 1000 to 1008. I changed it to 0 to 7 and now error solved..